# What is the meaning of "Do you know this actor?"

Tags: word-usage

"Do you know this actor?"

Is this question asking if you have a personal relationship with the actor?

If you want to ask if someone has some knowledge about the actor (their name, films where they appear, etc.), what would you say?

Comment: I'd say no generally, but it would really depend on the context.  What is the context of the question? Where did you hear this?

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/311094/is-it-possible-to-know-someone-youve-never-met/311108  This is my previous question.  I learnt that "I know John" means John and I know each other.  So, I wondered what "I know this actor" would mean.

Comment: I thought I had seen a similar question recently! The answer given there makes it clear that "I know him" _usually_ means "I'm personally acquainted with him", but depending on context it _can_ mean "I'm familiar with his work".

Answer (score 1):

Unless the two participants in the conversation actually work in the film industry, it's going to be far more common that "Do you know this actor?" means, 'Are you aware of this person & at least some of their work?' - leading to answers along the lines of, "Yes, they were great in [movie name]" or "No. What were they in?"

If someone were to know them personally, then the answer would immediately differentiate. "Yes, we met in Cannes last year." would be a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 0):

"To know someone" can be used in a quite general sense. It's meaning is very dependent on context. It can range from a simple familiarity/knowledge that a person exists, to something much more personal such as a close friendship. In Biblical language "to know someone" was often used as a euphemism for having a sexual relationship with someone. If you ask "Do you know (someone)?" it could elicit a range of responses.

Some examples.

Q: Do you know James?  A: Yes, I'm acquainted with him. We worked for the same company.

versus

Q: Do you know Alice?  A:Yes, very well! She's my best friend.